# Como puedo implementar un try-catch en un ciclo do while para una calculadora en JAVA?

Tags: java, poo

Estoy intentando hacer una calculadora de números complejos en Java, las clases y las instancias están funcionando bien, el problema es que quiero usar try-catch para controlar el error en el caso de que el dato ingresado sea un valor no numérico, he leído bastante(o quizás no tanto) pero no logro encontrar la solución, Intente hacer un try-catch en el metodo de menu, pero me exige que retorne algo despues del catch

```
    public class App {
private static Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

//Metodo de menu
public static int Menu(){
    int opcion;
      
    System.out.println("\n" + "Calculadora de numeros complejos" + "\n");
    System.out.println("0.Salir");
    System.out.println("1.Sumar");
    System.out.println("2.Restar");
    System.out.println("3.Multiplicar");
    System.out.println("4.Dividir" + "\n");
    System.out.println("Elija una opcion: ");
    opcion = teclado.nextInt();
    return opcion;
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int opcion;
    double real, imaginario;
    Aritmetica ari1, ari2, ari3;
    
    //Ciclo do/while para inicializar el menu
    do{
    opcion = Menu();
    //Switch para probar operacion aritmetica deseada y ciclar mientras se escoja una de las opciones propuestas al usuario
        switch(opcion){
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Adios");
                break;
            case 1:
                //aqui va el ingreso de numeros y se instancia la operacion correspondiente
                break;
            case 2:
                //aqui va el ingreso de numeros y se instancia la operacion correspondiente
                break;    
            case 3:
                //aqui va el ingreso de numeros y se instancia la operacion correspondiente
                break;
            case 4:
                //aqui va el ingreso de numeros y se instancia la operacion correspondiente
                break;            
        }
    }while((opcion!=5 && opcion != 0) && (opcion > 0 && opcion <5) );   

}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mostranos como implementaste el try catch, asi podemos corregir lo que hiciste mal...

Answer (score 1):

Logre con un while solucionar el problema para que al momento de que el usuario ingrese informacion no acepte valores no numericos

```
    while (!teclado.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Ingrese opciones solamente");
        teclado.next();
    }return teclado.nextInt();
```